# Distributions when only one physical node

Tags: optimization, distributed-databases, azure-synapse-analytics

Working on Azure Synapse, we have for now around 30 tables on a dev environment.

I want to optimize the tables before replicating them in qal and prod env.

As far as I understand, we only have one physical node: Subscription DW100c, and when running `SELECT DISTINCT(pwd_node_id) FROM sys.pdw_nodes_indexes` I get a unique id.
At the moment, everything is round-robin and because there is unicity of node, I guess that transitionning some to hash won't lead in any improvement of performance, and will rather lead to a loss in loading time for the PowerBI semantic models that refresh every day.

Could you please confirm?

Comment: "*I want to optimize the tables before replicating them in qal and prod env.*" - And what is the problem with them currently that you are trying to optimize? "*I guess that transitionning some to hash won't lead in any improvement of performance*" - What does this mean?...improve performance in what regard?

Comment: Some of them aren't small (20+ million growing) and the queries are long. Note that we rarely perform joins on those bigger tables.

Comment: FWIW, 20 million rows is still small as far as modern data is concerned. If you have a long running query, it's unlikely due to the size of your table, and rather more to do with how you wrote the query and / or architected the database. You'd have to provide the specific query, and it's execution plan, if you wanted help performance tuning though. I'm still unsure where hashing comes into play here.